# Matching output of sample() with rbinom() in R?

Tags: r, random, sampling, resampling

Maybe this is too simple of a question but shouldn't `A` and `B` be exactly equal in my below `R` code:

```
set.seed(0)
A <- sample(0:1, 50, prob = rep(.5, 2), replace = T) # 'A' is HERE
plot(table(A))

set.seed(0)
B <- rbinom(50, 1, .5)  # 'B' is HERE
plot(table(B))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we take the negation of 'B', it will be the same i.e. if we look the output of 'B', it has 0 values that takes the same position where it is 1 in A and viceversa

```
identical(A, +!B)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or instead of doing the negation, create 'A', by doing the reverse i.e. 1:0

```
set.seed(0)
A <- sample(1:0, 50, prob = rep(.5, 2), replace = TRUE)
identical(A, B)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @rnorouzian By checking the output, the 1s and 0s in `rbinom` is reversed for each position

Comment: @rnorouzian `rbinom` is implemented in C, may be have to check the source code.  But, I tried the `sample` with characters and it is almost the same behavior i.e. try with `sample(c("A", "B")` or `sample(c("B", "A")` or `sample(c("0", "1")` or `sample(c("1", "0")` (as here)

Comment: @rnorouzian  It is an interesting question as `sample` is `sample.int` and it is implemented in C.  So, if you do `pryr::show_c_source(.Internal(sample(n, size, replace, prob)) )` it will direct to the random.C source code

Comment: @rnorouzian  Looks like it is answered :=)

Comment: Akrun, thanks. Yes, the answer was it is impossible, though.